# display title element of img on overlaying div

Tags: jquery, wordpress

**Situation**
My client wants a grid of images on his frontpage that all link to a different part of the website. On hover there should be an overlay with some text. And all this in Wordpress so he can change the images, text or even add or remove images.

**Solution (so far)**
My solution for the image grid is fairly simple. A table with three cells in one row and in every cell images are added beneath each other.
Not a very responsive solution, but it works fine.

For the overlay with text I came up with the idea to wrap the image in a container div with javascript (jquery) and add the overlay to that container div. For the text and to keep it dynamic and changeable for my client, I thought I would extract the title attribute, something the client can fill in when adding the image in Wordpress.

This is what I have so far:

```
$(function() {
    $("img[class^='imglink']").wrap('<div class="overlay-container"></div>');
    $("img[class^='imglink']").after('<div class="overlay"></div>');

    var imgTitle = $("img[class^='imglink']").attr('title');
    $('.overlay').html(imgTitle);
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PaulvdDool/zurrh3r6/5/)

**Problem**
I call on all the images who's classes start with `imglink-`. As a condition, the client has assign a class starting with this to the image, something he'll be able to do in Wordpress (easily). All these images are being wrapped by a container div. Easy as that. This way, the client can also add images that won't have overlays on hover.
But I can't figure out how to extract the title attributes from these images and display them in the corresponding overlays.
In the fiddle mentioned above you'll see the title attribute of the first image displayed in both overlays.

Does anyone have any suggestion as to how display the correct title attribute in the corresponding overlay?

Comment: Always try to add the relevant code in your question itself, in addition to your JSFiddle link. Links can always end up broken and future visitors with the same problem wouldn't be able to see your code anymore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have it mostly right.  Wrap your DOM changes in a `.each` function and you'll be golden.  Like so:

```
$(function() {
    
    $("img[class^='imglink']").each(function(){
        var imgTitle = $(this).attr('title');
        $(this).wrap('<div class="overlay-container"></div>');
        $(this).after('<div class="overlay">'+imgTitle+'</div>');
        
    });
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/zurrh3r6/6/

#### Edit:

for clarification, what was wrong in your code was that you were overriding your overlay content.  This line sets the value to kitten 1 (It only grabs the first one because there are multiple):

```
var imgTitle = $("img[class^='imglink']").attr('title');
```

Then when you set the overlay, you're setting the value for all `.overlay` elements on this line:

```
$('.overlay').html(imgTitle);
```

Comment: This works fine! Thank you. I think it's time for me to look more into the each function. Expand the knowledge!

Answer (score 0):

jQuery has a .siblings selector, so you can easily find the neighbour of your img element with a single line of jQuery code. See the fiddle here:

http://jsfiddle.net/zurrh3r6/8/

This snippet will loop through all of the overlays, and get the title of the img tag nex to it:

```
$('.overlay').each(function(){
    var imgTitle = $(this).siblings('img').attr('title');
    $(this).html(imgTitle);
});
```